# How to wait for messages from 2 users (aiogram)

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

How do you link two users? Suppose there is a bot that, after receiving the start command, replies, 'Ask the second user to write {code} to the bot.

'When the second user enters the {code} command, the first user receives the message, '{user.id} entered this code.'

The code itself will be generated using `random.choice()` from a list of words, for example: 'loremipsum,' 'randomtext,' etc

Answer (score 1):

You can just create table in db for this action

```
cur.execute(f'''CREATE TABLE {user1_id + user2_id} IF NOT EXISTS (
    
    )''')
```

with columns `user1_id`, `user_2id`, `code`.

And when user sends code, if it is the right code, I get from table secon `user_id` and send him message after this just drop this table

Comment: Спасибо, но хотелось бы без ДБ и файлов, с ними очень часто проблемы и кучу лишних строк